# How to fix error in native query : it is showing syntax error near or at

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table name group having fields id , name etc. but i only want to fetch id and name so for this i made a separate (data transfer object).

I wrote a database query to return the Data transfer object but i don't know why it is showing an error : syntax error at or near"."

```
@Query(value = "select new 
com.colo.dashboard.api.dto.GroupNameDto(g.id, g.name) from groups 
g", nativeQuery = true)
List<GroupNameDto> getGroupsName();
```

GroupNameDto:

```
public class GroupNameDto {

private Long id;
private String name;

public GroupNameDto(Long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}}
```

actual result:
syntax error near or at .

Comment: `"select new com.colo.dashboard.api.dto.GroupNameDto(g.id, g.name) from groups g"` is not valid SQL. I really recommend you follow a Spring JPA tutorial, because there are too many incorrect things going on here.

Comment: can you please exactly let me know what is the problem with query because i have already searched from too many sites and found same result. thanks

Comment: I echo with @JacobG. it's not a valid native SQL query

Comment: You can create objects from a jpql query, not a native query. Try it.

Comment: Remove the `nativeQuery = true`, it is not a native query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Entity
public class GroupName {

private Long id;
private String name;

public GroupName(Long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

---

```
public class GroupNameDto {

private Long id;
private String name;

public GroupNameDto(Long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

---

```
@Query(value="select new com.colo.dashboard.api.dto.GroupNameDto(g.id, g.name) from GroupName g")
List<GroupNameDto> getGroupsName();
```

Comment: Actually that name "groups" is my entity name which u have only changed into GroupName. still it is not working ..thanks

Comment: I have also removed nativeQuery = true, can you share your groups class and error is same or something new

Comment: thankyou so much it's working now.

Comment: Welcome @Bushra please accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: @Query(value = "select new com.colo.dashboard.api.dto.GroupPermission(g.id,g.name,new ArrayList<>().add(new permission(p.id,p.name)),g.status) from groups g join groups_permission_ids gp on g.id=gp.groups_id join permission p on p.id=gp.permission_ids_id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<GroupPermission> getGroupAndPermission();      can you please suggest me  how to pass arraylist in this @patel